# How could i make a clean unwrap with the array modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, modifiers

I´m new to Blender

I´m making a sauna bench asset for UE4, and I make the planks with the array modifier, when I tried to make de UVs, I watch tutorials but its like I cant find the solution that I want**

So how do you recommend to do it? I would like to know how to randomize the way that the material is applied in the planks, so they don't have all the planks with the same look.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier if all your planks were in the same object (Ctrl+J). Then you can select all faces, and in UVEditor call UV/Pack Island. It will spread all your planks inside the UV space, so each plank will have be unique.
Before that, you may want to straighten your islands, just select them and rotate them (R)